# Plus sign is getting type automatically

Tags: windows-7, keyboard

I am facing weird problem from couple of weeks. Whenever I will logged in my personal computer and try to open windows explorer, browser, any other stuff '+' sign is getting typed automatically.

I have tried removing plus keys from keyboard but it doesn't solve my problem.

Because of this I am unable to type anything in browser window or any word, text file.

I have checked run anti virus programm also but no virus is found on my machine.

So, can anyone suggest how to resolve this problem ?

Regards,
Rohit Pundlik

Comment: Could you specify exactly what kind of a computer or laptop you have? For problems like these it's often make- or model-specific, and also it'll help future users more accurately if a solution is indeed found. Good luck.

Answer (score 1):

No way to tell what's wrong, but I can make a few suggestions:

1. Hit Fn+F11, especially if you've got an Acer or HP.
2. Hold both shift keys simultaneously for a few seconds.
3. Update your BIOS.

If it's a wireless keyboard, try new batteries, and if it's a USB keyboard, try a different USB port. If none of the above work, then try to borrow someone else's keyboard to see if it's just the keyboard (unfortunately, often it's not).

And do report back here so we know what you ended up doing!